# Alien man and young sister get almost hijacked. Sister gets arrested with hijacker friends and brother works with hijacker to help her escape

Tags: story-identification

The brother and sister are delivery people for space mercs. The brother fought in an old war by piloting a spaceship and he's really good at it. The leader of the three hijackers works with the brother to help get his friends out of what he calls the most secure prison the galaxy.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking for an identification? Is this a movie, a TV show, a comic book, a novel, a short story, or what? Around when did you see/hear/read it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.